# SAS macro code to generate mean sales for a particular year

Tags: macros, sas

I am trying to write a macro code that generates average sales for a particular year. Say today I want report for year=2008 and tomorrow for year=2009.
The data has Order_date variable which is in format mmddyy10.

I am trying to achieve that by the following code:

```
%macro yearly(yr=%sysfunc(year("&sysdate"d )); 

proc means data=salesxls;
class &yr;
where year(order_date) == &yr;
title "yearly avg sales for &yr";
run;

%mend yearly;
```

This is not working. The reason could be the %sysfunc I used to extract the year. Any help would be appreciated.
 P.S A Macro newbie here

EDIT:
The code for single year that works is as follows:

```
data new;

set work.salesxls;

yr=year(Order_date);     /** I extracted the year from Order_date)**/

run;

proc means data=new mean;

class yr;

var total_retail_price;

where yr=2008;

run;
```

In the code above I first created a data set which has extracted year. Then I used that data for proc means procedure.

Comment: To write a macro first start with working code. What does your proc means look like for a single year, with no macro logic that works. Then we can help you turn it into a macro.

Comment: You may find these two links useful: This one shows how to use formats to summarize your data at differnet levels, ie year. https://gist.github.com/statgeek/0cae5568752959b035516d6ac07a20fb#file-sas_format_proc_means_summary-sas and this one shows how to turn a program into a macro: https://github.com/statgeek/SAS-Tutorials/blob/master/Turning%20a%20program%20into%20a%20macro.md

Comment: @Reeza please see edit

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can simplify this:

1. Move the YEAR calculation into the WHERE clause
2. Apply a format to the ORDER_DATE variable, YEAR4., which will display and aggregate it as a year.
3. Replace 2008 in code with &year.

   ```
   %macro yearAvg(year=);
   proc means data=salesxls mean;
   where year(order_date)=&year.;
   class order_date;
   format order_date year4.;
   var total_retail_price;
   run;
   %mend;

   %yearAvg(year=2008);
   ```